# CAT5 cable is not working directly to PC

Tags: networking, cat5

Here is what my current network looks like. The Second switch in the diagram is upstairs to the rest of the network.

[image: Network diagram]

My issue comes when I try to connect the cable from switch 1 directly to the PC upstairs. When I plug it into the PC it isn't recognized at all (no lights on the network adapter in the back of the PC, however if I plug it back into Switch 2 it works just fine. I'm trying to bypass switch 2 completely since the Smart Display can use WiFi and switch 2 is only a 10/100, whereas my router and switch 1 is 10/100/1000.

Is there any reason that a cable would work in a switch, but not directly to the PC? For reference the cable is 25 feet long.

Comment: Have you confirmed your PC's NIC is not the issue?

Comment: Yes, if I move the computer to another location it connects just fine. Or if I connect it to the switch 2 in the diagram.

Comment: You've also tried connecting the PC to different ports on switch 1?

Comment: There is no reason why a cable would work through a switch, but not directly to the PC. Please clarify by providing the make and model of the switches by clicking on [edit].. Cabling can be as long as 328' (100m) if the switches adhere to the Gigabit or 100MB/s Ethernet standards. Will PC1 upstairs work OK if you bypass Switch 1 AND Switch 2 and connect it directly to the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, and thank you all for suggestions. The cable is partially damaged. When I plug it into the switch the cable falls downward from the switch and works. When I turn it sideways to plug into the PC, the cable is pulled to the side and apparently one of the pins pulls away from the plug. Jiggling the cable makes it work again. Now I just need to buy a crimper and some connectors to re-do that cable end.